# consulta en la base de datos: con tkinter y sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3

Estoy comenzando con python y he creado un pequeño script en el que se escribe un texto y se guarda en una base de datos sqlite con varios parámetros del texto escrito: número de caracteres, hora en la que se escribió, fecha, etc, y todo parece funcionar muy bien. 
Ahora he querido usar parte de ese archivo script a tkinter (para hacerlo algo más visual) partiendo de este código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

root.title("Programa prueba")
root.configure(background="SkyBlue4")
color_boton=("gray77")

Label(root, bg="SkyBlue4", text="").pack()  
Label(root, bg="SkyBlue4", text="Dame la fecha en formato hh:mm:ss").pack()

def show_text():
    global label_text
    label_text.set(entry_text.get())

entry_text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, width=10, justify=CENTER, textvariable=entry_text)
entry.pack()

button = Button(root, text="Comprobar", command=show_text)
button.pack()

label_text = StringVar()
label = Label(root, bg="SkyBlue4", textvariable=label_text)
label.pack()

conexion = sqlite3.connect("basedatos.db")
cursor = conexion.cursor() 

resultado = StringVar()
resultado = entry.get()
cursor.execute("SELECT texto FROM mensajes WHERE hora=?", (resultado,))
textofinal = cursor.fetchone()
textototal = textofinal[0]

espacio = Label(root, bg="SkyBlue4", text="").pack()    

label = Label(root, bg="SkyBlue4", text=textototal)
label.pack()  

conexion.close()

mensaje = StringVar()
mensaje.set("Bienvenido a Programa prueba")
monitor = Label(root, textvar=mensaje, justify='left', anchor='sw')
monitor.pack(side="bottom", anchor='sw', fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Me gustaría que al pulsar el botón "button" generara un valor (que sería igual a la cadena de texto que se teclee en Entry) y fuera igual a "resultado" para que, al compararlo en la base de datos, encontrara ese "resultado" de la columna hora y mostrara el texto, pero no logro obtener lo deseado.

La base de datos tiene esta estructura.

```
Nombre de la tabla en sqlite3: mensajes

id | dias | fecha     | hora    | longitudtexto | texto
1   1      24/04/20    17:48:02  10              Bien hecho
```

No sé si me explicado. Pido disculpas de antemano por si no me he explicado de forma correcta.

Mil gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Sin comprendo bien, tienes problemas para hacer una consulta en la base de datos, sin nada qué ver con el error que pones en el título de la pregunta. Por favor, pon un título más acorde a la pregunta y, a ser posible, muestra algunos registros de la tabla `mensajes` para saber algo de su estructura.

Comment: Ok, ChemaCortes, edito el mensaje. Gracias!

Comment: ¿y has probado a cambiar la _query_ con `cursor.execute("SELECT texto FROM mensajes WHERE hora='17:48:02'")`?

Comment: Hola @ChemaCortes, Si pongo el valor en el código funciona perfectamente, pero el valor debe entrar a través del entry. No sé cómo poder conseguirlo. :(

Comment: No sé si me estoy perdiendo algo. Si en el `entry` pones `17:48:02` ¿no funciona?

Comment: Hola @ChemaCortes! Se supone que cuando escribes un texto por teclado en el `Entry` , este te tiene que devolver una cadena de caracteres en forma de variable, en este caso sería `label_text`. Hasta ahí bien, pero ese string de texto se tiene que comparar con el campo `hora` de la base de datos, y dar el resultado `texto` de la base de datos.